# How to change Python comment font style in the latest VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, font-style

Seems like with the latest VS Code update, all the comment font style has gone Italic. Does anyone know how to change the font back to normal? Thanks.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think you may have a theme (or extension) that is changing the comment font style.  My comments are not italic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is set in your settings:

`"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "comments": {
          "fontStyle": ""
      }
  }`

Other possible way with more controls is `Cmd+Shift+P` -> Select `Developer: Generate Color Theme From Current Settings`.
Then edit what you need, save it to new theme and load/activate it.