# How to change Python comment font style in JupyterLab code cells and code editor?

Tags: python, css, jupyter, jupyter-lab

There's quite a lot answers about how to change font family for all contents. However, I want to make syntax-specific changes, for example, change Python comment font style from italic to normal. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

There is a similar question for doing the same thing in VS Code. [How to change Python comment font style in the latest VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209714/how-to-change-python-comment-font-style-in-the-latest-vs-code)

Answer (score 1):

For JupyterLab 3.x you can install [jupyterlab-fonts](https://github.com/deathbeds/jupyterlab-fonts) and configure it to swap the font of tokens with `cm-comment` class in the `Advanced Settings Editor` → `Fonts`:

```json
{
  "styles": {
    ".CodeMirror-line span.cm-comment": {
      "fontFamily": "Consolas",
      "fontStyle": "normal"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: comment font style]

Alternatively you could:

- write a very simple JupyterLab extension providing a single-line CSS equivalent of the above
- open a feature request on [jupyterlab-fonts/issues](https://github.com/deathbeds/jupyterlab-fonts/issues) proposing a per-token customization from the GUI if you fancy that (and even better, contribute).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would certainly try out jupyterlab-fonts on my computer at home. But I'm probably not able to use it on my work computer, which is running JupyterLab 1.2.6 and lack customization flexibility due to admin reasons.
Could you explain more on writing a simple extension? Can I do this changing only stuff in my .jupyter folder?

Comment: On JupyterLab 3.x you could create a prebuilt extension which you would install using `pip` (locally), but it was only introduced in 3.0 so JupyterLab 1.x does not support that (it would require Node.js to be installed and rebuilding lab which likely means you cannot do that either). So the way forward would be to nudge admins to upgrade (we do not actively support 1.x anymore, recent security fixes were exception).

Comment: There is an [extension tutorial](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_tutorial.html) and [extension developer guide](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_dev.html) but If you want to make a CSS-only extension (which is not a full-blown theme) I would just use JavasSript (rather than the default TypeScript) cookiecutter: https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-cookiecutter-js and after setting it up the only thing you need to change is adding styles in `style/base.css` file (which already exists).