# Adjusting Font Size and Color for Comments in JupyterLab Python Mode

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter-lab

I am using JupyterLab to teach a course in Python. Suppose we are in **Python mode** within a Jupyter cell, crafting Python code accompanied by some comments. Is it feasible to selectively enhance the font size and color **exclusively for the comments**?

Perhaps it is too much to expect from Jupyter. My students would appreciate larger comments to better understand the explanations accompanying the Python code.

Comment: Why not simply split the code into multiple cells, and preceed each chunk of code with a markdown cell that documents the code?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The title is fixed now.

Comment: There was already a similar question [here entitled 'How to change Python comment font style in JupyterLab code cells and code editor?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293957/8508004). Did you try that answer? That was version 3 and the specifics may have changed slightly in JupyterLab 4+. That looks to get you part of the way towards this. I don't know customizable the size may be there.